# What is error 5 in chartboost?

Tags: ios, iphone, error-code, chartboost

I integrate chartboost sdk in my app. I use latest sdk and perform each step according to documentation.

When I run the app Chartboost ad is not coming and when I log the error it gives me error code **5**. Can anyone tell me what is error code **5** in chartboost?

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution!!!

The error 5 means that there is a network error. One reason for its occurrence is incorrect chartboost Id or chartboost signature.

In my case I enter wrong Id that's why I am getting this error and advertise is not displaying.